# Connection refused to port 8440

Tags: connection, ufw

I am new to ubuntu. I installed a Talend sandbox and installed ambari server. The setup was successful. Also I can SSH into the virtual box running ubuntu. Also I can open the talend pages like localhost:4040, localhost:8088 or localhost 50700. But when I try to open the ambari setup page localhost:8440 I get the connection refused. Also on the remote machine I can open the :4040 but cannot open :8088 or :50700 or :8440. I disabled the ufw and also added the ports to it, still its not working.

Please help. my knowledge to ubuntu is very limited though I am trying to learn as much I can.
Thanks in Advance.